# Google photos shows no photos in All tab

Tags: nexus-5, google-plus-photos

I have been noticing that the Google+ Photos application does not show any images in the All tab (the Highlights tab works fine). I have a lot of photos but they show up fine in the stock Gallery app. Any ideas?

The device is the Nexus 5 which does not have an SD card.

I tried clearing the cache (suggested [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/46449/15)) but the Photos app is not listed in Settings > Apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google+ Photos doesn't exist separately - it lies within Google+ main application. I mean Google+ Photos app comes along with Google+. So you need to clear the data of Google+ in app manager. Also you can uninstall the updates of Google+ and update again if clearing the data doesn't work.

Comment: Good call pointing that out. Clearing cache of Google+ did not solve problem however.

Comment: Have you tried the second method?

Comment: Second method did it, thanks! Saw the images when I uninstalled the updates. Reinstalled the updates and as it says "Updating Library..." at the top, the images are there.